# Guava eventbus dispatching error

Tags: java, android, guava

I'm developing an android application, and I'm using guava eventbus.
I get ambiguous errors about not being able to dispatch events. 
How can I investigate such problems ? and how can I get more information about the exception ?

this is a sample exception message :

```
04-12 20:46:35.829   9971-11208/xxx.android.init E/default﹕ Could not dispatch event: xxx.android.presentation.control.MainActivity@21139768 to public void xxx.android.presentation.control.MainActivity.showToast(xxx.core.event.EventShowToast)
```

ps: I replaced our company class path prefix with `xxx`.

Comment: Is there any additional stack trace which follows this message to hint why there might be a problem?

Comment: @AndyTurner : Unfortunately, no. This is what is puzzling me !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if a subscriber throws an exception.

You can replace the default logger with your own, by providing an implementation of `com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberExceptionHandler` to your `EventBus` during construction.

For example:

```
import com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberExceptionContext;
import com.google.common.eventbus.SubscriberExceptionHandler;

class CustomExceptionHandler implements SubscriberExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleException(Throwable exception, SubscriberExceptionContext context) {
        System.out.println("Handler '"+context.getSubscriber()+"' could not handle '"+context.getEvent().getClass().getName()+"'["+context.getEvent()+"]: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
EventBus eventBus = new EventBus(new CustomExceptionHandler());
```